# Skipping or make dir if dir does not exist php

Tags: php

I am trying to open the latest file in a directory that is connected to different usernames. However, some usernames dont have uploaded directory and i want to skip those users or created the directory doesnt matter whichever one. This is my current code.

```
 <?php $path =  base_url(''.$value['username']) . '/' . 'uploaded';) 

$latest_ctime = 0;
$latest_filename = '';    

$d = dir($path);

while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
  $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
  // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
  if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
    $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
    $latest_filename = $entry;
  }
}?>
```

The error i get when i upload this is

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: dir(https://www.domain.com/pdfs/bob/uploaded): failed to open dir: not implemented

Filename: views/search.php

Line Number: 71
```

i tried searching and tried some mkdir stuff i found that did not work. Even the latest file one i found on stackoverflow.

Comment: you haven't made any directory in code or check for existence of directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to create directory in php if not exist.

```
if (!is_dir('path/to/directory')) {
    mkdir('path/to/directory', 0777, true);
}
```

Here I am describe your code..

```
    <?php $path =  base_url(''.$value['username']) . '/' . 'uploaded';) 

    $latest_ctime = 0;
    $latest_filename = '';  

    if (!is_dir($path)) {
        mkdir($path, 0777, true);
    }

    $d = dir($path);

    while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      $filepath = "{$path}/{$entry}";
      // could do also other checks than just checking whether the entry is a file
      if (is_file($filepath) && filectime($filepath) > $latest_ctime) {
        $latest_ctime = filectime($filepath);
        $latest_filename = $entry;
      }
    }
?>
```

Note : You have to pass the path in `is_dir()` and `mkdir()` function. You can not pass the URL in these function.

Comment: i had to use the code that MajicBob posted below for my path. But other than that everything else that was posted above worked and also same thing was posted spaniard. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if the dir exists before try to open it. Try to use [is_dir()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.is-dir.php) like:

```
if (is_dir($path)) {
    $d = dir($path);
} else {
    mkdir($path, 0700);         // Change the permission as you need.
    $d = dir($path);            // Since the folder is being just created you could return
}
```

If you prefer to skip those user you could change the code inside the `else{}` to `exit` the script, or whatever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

In PHP dir() works on the filesystem, not on URLs. What you need to use will depend on exactly where the files are and how your hosting is setup. Based on the info try something like:

```
$path = '<wwwroot>/pdfs/' . $value['username'] . '/uploaded';
```

That should get you a Directory object if it exists. If you don't know what your www root is you can try something like:

```
$path = __DIR__ . '/pdfs/' . $value['username'] . '/uploaded';
```

That will be based on the current directory of the file you are executing.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read the directory from the URL. You need to pass it the path of the directory in the filesystem.
eg.

```
'/home/your_app/pdfs/' . $value['username']) . '/' . 'uploaded'
```